# AI in turn-based strategy

Tags: ai, turn-based-strategy

Which artificial intelligence architecture will work best in a turn-based strategy game. It is similar to the games from the Europe Universalis series.
In the game it is possible to:

- create trade routes
- colonize provinces
- conquer provinces
- build buildings in provinces
- build fleets, armies
- conduct diplomacy (wars, alliances, vassalisation, trade agreements).
- provinces have resources etc.

I read about HTN, GOAP and utility methods. I think the finite state machine and the behavior trees are not going to work in such game. I also don't intend to create an extremely complex AI. I am aware that this is a large undertaking. I would like to be extended and improved in the future.
I am thinking of creating a module that analyzes the state of the world. The result of the analysis would be such factors as: economic development, military development and the development of diplomacy. On the basis of the value of these factors e.g. HTN (or another solution) would create plans for the development of the state.
What other approaches could be used?

Comment: Your proposed plan sounds like a reasonable starting point. Is there a specific problem you've found with that approach that answers here should focus on addressing? If not, asking for any and all alternatives is liable to get you solutions that are no better or maybe even worse for your needs than the one you've already thought of, or maybe no solutions at all (since folks usually like to have a specific issue to solve, rather than offer shots in the dark). I'd recommend making a start with your HTN idea, and post here when you get stuck or observe a specific problem with it.

Comment: I know it is difficult to tell from the amount of information provided in my post which solution works best, but there maybe are some rules that say, for example, that in most turn-based strategy games, the finite state machine is a bad idea. Perhaps there are developers of similar games here who can say what worked for them and what did not.

Comment: Or "maybe" there aren't such generally-agreed-upon rules. Often, in game development, there aren't. Given the low traffic volume we get on this site, and the low response rate we get for vague questions, I'd say your chances of getting a good-enough solution are much better by trying what you've thought of so far. Along the way, you'll learn a lot more specifics about your game's particular needs, which aspects of them HTN serves well, and where it leaves room for improvement. Then you can ask a focused question about how to improve your solution in those specific areas.

Comment: Ok. So there is nothing else but to try my solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you made any progress on this project/question?  I am currently working on a similar type of game, and have had almost the exact same questions as you.  I am currently trying to implement a TBS AI using GOAP, but am very concerned about the size of the search space, especially into the mid- and late-game.  I'd be happy to share what I have learned so far, let me know if you're interested.  I personally find so much conflicting information online regarding how best to approach AI game architecture, it makes it very hard to know if you are going down the right path.